# Does bash provide support for using pointers?

Tags: bash

Simple question. Does the bash shell have any support for using pointers when writing a shell script?

I am familiar with expansion notation, `${var[@]}` when iterating over the array `$var`, but it is not clear this is utilizing pointers to iterate over the array indices. Does bash provide access to memory addresses like other languages?

If bash does not support using pointers, what other shells do?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A pointer (to a location of *memory*) is not really a useful concept in anything higher-level than C, be it something like Python or the shell. References to objects are of course useful in high-level languages, perhaps even necessary for building complex data structures. But in most cases thinking in terms of memory addresses is too low level to be very useful.

In Bash (and other shells), you can get the values of array elements with the `${array[index]}` notation, assign them with `array[index]=...` and get the number of elements in the array with `${#array[@]}`. The expression inside the brackets is an arithmetic expression. As a made-up example, we could add a constant prefix to all array members:

```
for ((i=0 ; i < ${#array[@]} ; i++ )) ; do
    array[i]="foo-${array[i]}"
done
```

(If we only cared about the values, and not the indexes, just `for x in "${array[@]}" ; do...` would be fine.)

With [*associative* or sparse arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays), a numerical loop doesn't make much sense, but instead we'd need to fetch the array keys/indexes with `${!array[@]}`. E.g.

```
declare -A assoc=([foo]="123" [bar]="456")
for i in "${!assoc[@]}" ; do 
    echo "${assoc[$i]}"
done
```

---

In addition to that, Bash has two ways to point indirectly to another variable:

- *indirect expansion*, using [the `${!var}` syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), which uses the value of the variable whose *name* is in `var`, and
- *namerefs*, which need to be created with the [`declare` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-declare) (or the `ksh`-compatible synonym, `typeset`). `declare -n ref=var` makes `ref` a reference to the variable `var`.

Namerefs also support indexing, in that if we have `arr=(a b c); declare -n ref=arr;` then `${ref[1]}` will expand to `b`. Using `${!p[1]}` would instead take `p` as an array, and refer to the variable named by its second element.

In Bash, namerefs are literally that, references by *name*, and using a nameref from inside a function will use the local value of the named variable. This will print `local value of var`.

```
#!/bin/bash
fun() {
        local var="local value of var"
        echo "$ref";
}
var="global var"
declare -n ref=var
fun
```

BashFAQ has [a longer article on indirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006), too.

Comment: indirection is quite useful in higher level languages.  e.g. references in perl.  They're not the same as C pointers but they serve the same basic function.   Even bash can [access variables indirectly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224548/how-to-use-call-by-reference-on-an-argument-in-a-bash-function)...but IMO if you start writing code that makes significant use of the feature, you're better off starting from scratch with perl or something.  See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Comment: @cas, oh, absolutely. But it's probably better to think of them as pointing to _objects_, rather than memory addresses. (Even in C, there's a type involved.) I meant to note both indirect expansion and namerefs, but didn't have the time to do it immediately.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that the for-loop example is more naturally written `for foo in "${array[@]}" ; do ... done` unless you need the index for other purpose(s).

Comment: @WillCrawford, point. edited the example and noted.

Answer (score 11):

No, `bash` doesn't have "pointers", but it does have references:

```
$ spam="fred"
$ declare -n tripe=spam
$ echo $tripe
fred
$ tripe=juki
$ echo $spam
juki
```

From the `bash` man page:

> A variable can be assigned the nameref attribute using the -n option to
>   the `declare` or `local` builtin commands to create a nameref, or a reference to another variable.
>   This allows variables to be  manipulated  indirectly.   Whenever
>   the  nameref  variable  is  referenced,  assigned to, unset, or has its
>   attributes modified (other than using or changing the nameref attribute
>   itself),  the operation is actually performed on the variable specified
>   by the nameref variable's value.  A nameref  is  commonly  used  within
>   shell functions to refer to a variable whose name is passed as an argument
>   to the function.  For instance, if a variable name is passed to  a
>   shell function as its first argument, running
>
> ```
> declare -n ref=$1
> ```
>
> inside  the  function creates a nameref variable ref whose value is the
>   variable name passed as the first argument.  References and assignments
>   to  ref,  and  changes  to  its  attributes, are treated as references,
>   assignments, and attribute modifications to the variable whose name was
>   passed  as  $1.   If the control variable in a for loop has the nameref
>   attribute, the list of words can be a list of shell  variables,  and  a
>   name  reference will be established for each word in the list, in turn,
>   when the loop is executed.  Array variables cannot be given the nameref
>   attribute.   However,  nameref  variables can reference array variables
>   and subscripted array variables.  Namerefs can be unset  using  the  -n
>   option  to the `unset` builtin.  Otherwise, if `unset` is executed with the
>   name of a nameref variable as an argument, the variable  referenced  by
>   the nameref variable will be unset.

Answer (score 4):

No, shells do not use "pointers" (as understood in C).

Arrays could use indices: `echo "${array[2]}"` but the `@` in your example is not really a "pointer". It is a way to express "the list of array values". Something that the shell parser understand. Similar to the way a:

```
$ echo "$@"
```

expands to all the "Positional Parameters" list.

Answer (score 2):

While bash integer indexed arrays can be defined & accessed iteratively like so;

```
declare -a obj
obj+=("val1")
obj+=("val2")

for item in ${obj[@]}; do
  echo "${obj[${item}]} ${item}"
done
```

Associative or string based indexed arrays in bash require the following iterative definition;

```
declare -A obj
obj["key1"]="val1"
obj["key2"]="val2"

for item in ${!obj[@]}; do
  echo "${obj[${item}]} ${item}"
done
```

To answer the question regarding pointers and using one from bash; the internal functionality of the compiled bash binary does indeed make use of pointers to memory allocated on the stack and does expose similar functionality with the use of `eval`. See [indirect references]http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html)

There be dragons; use of `eval` should be used with caution due to security implications