# dynamic variable name in shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am deploying my shell script to a CI pipeline,  there are three different environment variables defined on CI:  `$prod`, `$dev`, `$test`.

My script managed to return the correct string value based on deployment type:

```
#!/bin/sh

my_env = // the checking logic

# the value of my_env is a string value of one of 'prod', 'dev' or 'test'
```

I wonder how can I make a variable out of `my_env` to point to the value to either `$prod` or `$dev` or `$test` dynamically now in my script?  I mean I can't `$my_env` since it only hold the string value e.g. `dev` instead of the actual value of `$dev`.

Comment: See: [Does bash provide support for using pointers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/413449/170373) (if you're using Bash). Though from a limited set of variables, it's easy enough do something like `case $varname in prod) stuff=$prod;; dev) stuff=$dev;; test) stuff=$test;; esac`

Comment: What language are you showing in the question? I don't know what `/bin/shell` is or what the syntax with `//` means.

Answer (score -1):

You can't: That's not how variables work.

But you can replace variables wherever you use them with calls to shell functions. That's easy, but it depends on what shell you use; sadly, your symbolic `/bin/shell` doesn't tell us!

For zsh, something like

```
check_env() {
   # do your checking
   print "prod"  # or "test" or whatever
}

...

if [[ "$(check_env)" = "prod" ]] {
   rm -rf /
}
```

Comment: How to tell what shell do I use in script? Do you mean there is another more specific header than `#!/bin/shell`? Could you please make an example for that?

Comment: I've never seen a /bin/shell on a linux system, I don't know where you have that from. So, I don't know what to tell you!

Comment: I think you need to read [What the first line in your script means](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268766/what-exactly-happens-when-i-execute-a-file-in-my-shell); honestly, you doing CI without knowing this is not great!

Comment: In general, "you can't" is wrong. For many shells in common use, it's quite possible (easy even in Bash, ksh and zsh, and doable with `eval` in any standard shell).

Comment: @ilkkachu but calling `eval` instead of a function is not easier; sure, I can expand a variable twice... but that would require me to formulate the check as variable expn expression, somehow.

Comment: I'm also not exactly sure what the `check_env` function is supposed to do here, or if it in fact works. `print("prod")` looks like it's treated as a glob (with the flags `p`, `r` and `od`), and it probably gives an error for a non-matching pattern

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks for spotting that; the parens are wrong, of course. `check_env` just contains exactly the checks that OP alludes to in their `// the checking logic`; the `print` is just an example "result" of that, illustrating how the information is passed from the function to the rest of the program logic

Comment: @user842225 The pathname following the [shebang](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is treated as the interpreter of the script. Simply do  `ls -l /bin/shell` (or whatever else you have, odds are it's actually `/bin/sh`) to check. You can also `file /bin/sh` if you have file(1) installed.