# Using grep and command line argument

Tags: command-line, grep, variable-substitution

I have a file `f1` with contents:

```
james john joe  
marie james  
joe   
don marie
```

I want to output the occurrence of the command line arguments in each line using `grep` in a shell script `s1.sh` with content:

```bash
#!/bin/bash   
for ((i = $# ; i > 0 ; i-- ))  
    do  
        grep -c $i f1  
    done
```

Say I execute it as follows:

```bash
s1.sh james joe
```

How do I make the script interpret the variable `i` as the positional parameter?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the script's argument, one at a time, in calls to `grep`, you don't need to do an arithmetic `for` loop:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

for pattern do
    grep -c -e "$pattern" f1
done
```

This `for` loop loops over the positional parameters, i.e. the argument to your script.  For each iteration, the value `$pattern` will be the next command-line argument.

I've also used `-e` with `grep` above to ensure that a pattern that starts with a dash is not mistakenly interpreted as an option to `grep`.  I have also quoted the pattern to avoid performing word splitting and filename globbing.

If the pattern is in fact a string and not a regular expression, then consider using `grep` with `-F`.

The list of positional parameters is available as `"$@"`, and the above loop implicitly uses this.  To loop with `"$@"`, use

```bash
for pattern in "$@"; do
   ...
done
```

Note that the quoting is essential, or you'll perform word splitting and filename globbing on the script's arguments.

No piece of shell code in this answer requires `bash`, so I'm using `/bin/sh` in the `#!`-line.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make the script interpret the variable `i` as the positional parameter?

Probably the easiest way to get the positional parameter indexed by a variable in Bash is to apply the array slice notation to `$@`. `"${@:n:k}"` expands to the positional parameters from *n* to *n+k-1*, just like `"${array[@]:n:k}"` expands to the array elements from `"${array[n]}"` to `"${array[n+k-1]}"`. *n* and *k* are evaluated using shell arithmetic, so you can do e.g. `"${@:a+b-1:1}"`. Just `"${@:i:1}"` gives the one parameter at position `i`.

Alternatively, the indirect expansion `${!var}` does deal with the positional parameters too, so e.g. with `i=2`, `"${!i}"` would give `"$2"`.
Well, that's shorter than the above, too. On the other hand, namerefs *don't* work with the positional parameters, `declare -n ref=2` gives an error...

See e.g. [Does bash provide support for using pointers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/413449/170373)

Another way is to copy the list of positional parameters to a named array, and then index that in the usual manner. `args=("$@")` to do the copy  and then use `"${args[i]}"`. Again, the index here is an arithmetic expansion.

---

Of course, if you're happy to access the positional parameters in *ascending* order, as is usual, and don't actually need the reverse order which you show, then just use `for x in "$@"; do ...` or `for x do ...` as in Kusalanda's answer.

But you could also utilize the same looping construct to invert the list of positional parameters first. E.g. this would print `dd cc bb aa`, even in plain sh without namers, indirect references or arrays:

```
set -- aa bb cc dd 
first=1
for x in "$@"; do
    # on first iteration, clear the list
    [ "$first" = 1 ] && set --  
    first=
    set -- "$x" "$@" 
done
echo "$@"
```