# Bash command logic help

Tags: bash

Could someone help me with Bash logic?

I don't think it's my environment, I think I'm having trouble getting my head around some simple logic. Can someone explain why/how the following happens, and if there's a way to alter the outcome?

```
number=6
echo $number
6
test=$number
echo $test
6
```

So far so good

```
number=11
echo $test
6
test=$number
echo $test
11
```

I have to issue `test=$number` again for 11 to be displayed. Obviously this is by design, is there a way to generate 11 as the response without issuing `test=$number` again?

Comment: `nameref`s as described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413479/70524 seems to be what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

This isn't C/C++/any other language with pointers. If you do `test=$number`, you assign the value of the variable `number` to the variable `test`, not the address. So changing `number` later won't affect the `test` variable at all.

Also, I would recommend you to not name your variable `test` since it is a built-in command. You can - nothing will break - but its not fancy^^

Comment: variables don't share the same namespace with commands, though, you can write `test "$test"` without any conflicts

Comment: You are right but isn't this still bad practice?

Comment: @ilkkachu Well, there's nothing _stopping_ you from naming variables like standard utilities or shell keywords, but it certainly does not help with reading the code.

Comment: @Kusalananda, no jaa, there's things like "enable", "time", "command" and "umask" that are rather generic or work as rather obvious nouns. (Of course that `test "$test"` above is rather obfuscated.)